# What socket options would you recommended for tunnels?

Tags: sockets, tcp, tunnel

I'm writing a custom tunnel (first there's a custom hello and then the connection becomes a tunnel), but it's pretty slow.

I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to increase speed.

One way to increase speed for connections that use short messages for instance would be to disable the nagle algorithm (TCP_NODELAY).

What would you recommend for tunneling?
I am tunneling RTSP and HTTP if that helps.

EDIT: The code is as simple as it could possibly be:

```
int remote_fd;
int local_fd;
int fdmax;
char buf[1 << 10];

fdset master_set, read_set;
FD_ZERO(&master_set);
FD_ZERO(&read_set);
FD_SET(remote_fd, &master_set);
FD_SET(local_fd, &master_set);

fdmax = remote_fd > local_fd ? remote_fd : local_fd;

//Connect both remote_fd and local_fd
...

while (1) {
    read_set = master_set;
    select(fdmax + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (FD_ISSET(local_fd, &read_set)) {
        int n = recv(local_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        send(remote_fd, buf, n, 0);
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(remote_fd, &read_set)) {
        int n = recv(remote_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        send(local_fd, buf, n, 0);
    }
}
```

I have omitted error handling and the code connecting the sockets to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be in your *code* rathar than the socket options. TCP_NODELAY may or may not help. Large socket and and receive huffers may help. Your code may be introducing latency. Show us some code.

Comment: @TomM: very nice, but 1 << 10 is only 1024. Raise that to at least 4096. And set the socket send and receive buffers to at least 32k. There is a wrinkle to handling EOS: if recv() returns zero, shutdown the target socket for writing, which transmits the EOS, and remember that you have done so, and if you have already done that to the source socket, close them both. This handles shutdowns by either peer correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestions. About the EOS - I already handle it by closing and reconnecting the socket right on the spot :)

Comment: @TomM that doesn't work if there was a shutdown. The connection is still open for business in the other direction, and closing it immediately is therefore wrong. You have to do as I said above.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that disabling the nagle algorithm would help much. You provide too little information to give any more specific help. Hence the rest of the answers are only guesses. You need to provide which platform/OS each end of the tunnels is on and which programming language you are using.

For instance. HTTP tunneling would benefit greatly if you compress the requests/responses. But that would use a lot more battery if you are on a handheld device.

RTSP would benefit if you used UDP instead of TCP since it's a real time protocol that doesn't really care if everything arrives properly.

Comment: why do you think that your tunnel is the one hurting performance?

Comment: Well, one end would be Linux. There is a very high chance the other end is Linux as well (cameras with embedded Linux probably). I am using c. I see what you mean about compression. However, since I am only tunneling, I don't want to be aware of the communication to that extent (too much code and complexity). About the RTSP, I see what you mean, but I think that these cameras use TCP and not UDP for RTSP. By the way, without the tunneling the speed is much higher.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I think the tunnel is the one that hurts performance, is that I have a way of checking it without a tunnel. In that way, the video loads much faster (and plays better).